# "ufunc 'hyp2f1' not supported for the input types" error

Tags: diff, sympy, numpy-ufunc

When I'm trying to run the following code:

```
    import math
    from scipy import special as spec    
    import numpy as np
    from sympy import *

    y = Symbol('y')
    x = spec.hyp2f1(1.5, 2.5, 1, y**2)
    ans = x.diff(y)
    print ans
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calc.py", line 74, in <module>
    x = spec.hyp2f1(1.5, 2.5, 1, y**2)
TypeError: ufunc 'hyp2f1' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

What the problem is and are there any other ways to differentiate the function hyp2f1 symbolically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. We cannot mix Sympy and Scipy in the way you want. The error message is saying that it does not take symbolic inputs
2. [This](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html?highlight=hypergeometric#hypergeometric-functions) shows how you can get Hypergeometric functions in Sympy. It also provides examples of how to use this function. I am not sure if Sympy can differentiate this symbolically for you.